# Deeplinks ionic Runtime Error object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, deep-linking

Hi im'using deeplinks

This are my dependencies and deeplinks configuration

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
"@angular/common": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
"@angular/router": "5.2.11",
"@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/autostart": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.33.1",
"@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "4.20",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/globalization": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/media": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/native-audio": "4.20",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.20",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "4.20",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
"@types/node": "^15.12.4",
"com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.1.18",
"cordova": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "3.0.1",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
"cordova-plugin-audioinput": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-autostart": "^2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
"cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.2.4",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
"cordova-plugin-ibeacon": "^3.8.1",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.3",
"cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
"cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^2.4.0",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
"cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.0",
"cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1",
"install": "^0.13.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
"ionic-image-loader": "^4.2.1",
"ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.22",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"rxjs": "5.5.11",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.29"},

"ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
    "URL_SCHEME": "myapp",
    "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "http",
    "DEEPLINK_HOST": "myapp.com",
    "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
  }
```

I have imported deeplinks in. my app.module.ts and set it to the providers.

And my app.component.ts looks somthing like this that's not all the code it has

```
import { Deeplinks } from '@ionic-native/deeplinks/ngx';

constructor(
    private deeplinks: Deeplinks,
  ) {
    this.deeplinks.route({
      '/about-us': LoginPage,
    }).subscribe(match => {
      // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
      // match.$args - the args passed in the link
      // match.$link - the full link data
      console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
    }, nomatch => {
      // nomatch.$link - the full link data
      console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
    });
```

And that's the error I get after compiling the app someone knows what it could be?

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Deeplinks.route (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93651:126)
at new MyApp (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:800:24)
at createClass (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12816:20)
at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12651:37)
at createViewNodes (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14109:53)
at createRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13998:5)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15423:42)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14706:12)
at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11603:46)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4355:29)
```